# "The term '***' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet" error thrown in Azure Powershell step in Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-rm

I have an Azure Powershell step in my release pipeline that calls the Invoke-RestMethod cmdlet to make a call to the kudu API.

At the point of creating the step is selected my Azure Subscription from the list of available subscriptions and it uses this to authenticate.

I was able to run the step successfully at first, getting the following output in the console log:

[image]

However, for every subsequent release now I am receiving the error `##[error]The term '***' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.` with the following output:

[image]

I haven't changed the powershell that the step actually runs. Could there be an issue with the way the release pipeline is authenticating and selecting the subscription? I see in the output that the TenantId is shown as ***, which is what the error message is complaining about, could that be the source of it?

Comment: It looks like that script is auto-generated?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem in your script. `***` is used to mask secret variables, so your script is probably doing something where it's trying to run the contents of a variable. Maybe something like `&$TenantId`.